# New Environment With Problems{1,2,3,...}

Tags: environments

How can I define a new environment such that the following tex code would produce the following output?

```
\begin{customproblemsenv}
   \item content1
   \item content2
\end{customproblemsenv}
```

---

**Problem 1.**  content1
**Problem 2.**  content2

---

Comment: A MWE would be very nice. On top, the problem can easily be solved by using more ways (e.g., `enumerate`- or `newenvironment`-like solution).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I can only make enumerate make items with numbers (1,2,3...) and characters ((a),(b),(c)...) . I'm more interested how it'd be done with environments though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to design lists with addition `label` formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\newlist{customproblemsenv}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[customproblemsenv]{
  label = \textbf{Problem \arabic*.}, 
  wide
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{customproblemsenv}
  \item content1
  \item content2
  \item \lipsum[3]
\end{customproblemsenv}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the above answer, the simpler code would be: (Check the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem))

```
  \documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}[label = Problem \arabic*]
     \item content1
     \item content2
  \end{enumerate}

  \end{document}
```